# Format of google app engine API url

Tags: javascript, api, google-app-engine

I created a google App engine project locally. Added a simple "Place" API and started the engine. I noticed that the server is waiting on `http://localhost:8888/_ah/api` base URL.

Now, I want to use the google javascript client API to call my API (I am assuming that is possible). So I created a simple local website and created a simple HTML/javascript page. Then I loaded the google javascript client library and executed.

Here is my page

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function load() {
        console.log("API client loaded");
        var ROOT = 'http://localhost:8888/_ah/api';
        gapi.client.load('getPlace', 'v1', function() {
          console.log("API called");
        }, ROOT);
      }
    </script>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=load"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div> Hello </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now, when I run it, I get a 404 error. Then I checked the URL that the browser places. It looks like this:

```
 http://<local>:8888/_ah/api/discovery/v1/apis/getPlace/v1/rpc?fields=methods%2F*%2Fid&pp=0
```

A few questions:

1. What I am doing should work correct ? (local app engine + javascript
       library)
2. What is the expected URL for app engine generated API ? (what is the "discovery" in the URL?)
3. What is the "rpc" at the end ? I am hoping to create REST API